# How to fetch the text spoken to cortana while the SpeechRecognitionResult.Text is returning "..." - Windows UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, speech-synthesis, cortana

While deep linking Windows UWP apps with cortana, I'm unable to fetch the text spoken. In the Voice Command Definition file I'm using a `<ListenFor>` element with {*} in order to allow user to speak anything, but I'm unable to fetch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to set up a VCD to accept freeform dictated text, you'll need to use a PhraseTopic field. See the [1.2 VCD spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn706593.aspx) for details.

For example, if you've got a Command block containing

```
<ListenFor> Take a note to {noteTopic} </ListenFor>
```

You'd want a corresponding PhraseTopic

```
<PhraseTopic Label="noteTopic" Scenario="Dictation">
</PhraseTopic>
```

There's various options (Subjects and Scenarios) you can use to refine the dictation service's behavior.

Comment: Thank you, It was really nice of you to guide me through.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Scenario="Search" and have you VCD look something like this:

```
<ListenFor> Take a note to {noteTopic} </ListenFor>
<PhraseTopic Label="noteTopic" Scenario="Search"/>
```