# UWP Cortana without PhraseList

Tags: c#, uwp, cortana

I want to implement Cortana with a UWP app, and I'm stuck to find a solution for asking a random content after the Command Prefix.

I know I could generate PhraseList dynamically, but, that's not the point here. Here is my actual VCD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
<CommandSet xml:lang="fr" Name="MyAppCommand_fr">
<CommandPrefix>MyApp</CommandPrefix>

<Command Name="showContent">

  <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforePhrase">{randomcontent}</ListenFor>
  <Feedback>Searching for {randomcontent}</Feedback>
  <Navigate />
</Command>

<!-- What I want here, is to get rid of PhraseList -->
<PhraseList Label="randomcontent">
  <Item>Random Content</Item>
</PhraseList>

</CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

Is there any way to accomplish that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the solution: Replace the PhraseList with `<PhraseTopic Label="randomcontent" Scenario="Dictation">
</PhraseTopic>`

Thanks for Andrew Pilley and his answer in this post: [UWP Cortana PhraseTopic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608991/how-to-fetch-the-text-spoken-to-cortana-while-the-speechrecognitionresult-text-i)

Answer (score 2):

you can also use:

```
 <PhraseTopic Label="searchParam" Scenario="Search"/>
```

so you would have:

```
<Command Name="showContent">    
  <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforePhrase">{randomcontent}</ListenFor>
  <Feedback>Searching for {randomcontent}</Feedback>
  <Navigate />
</Command>

<PhraseList Label="randomcontent" Scenario="Search"/>
```